# Does Jewish tradition hold the book of Jonah to be depicting historical events?

Tags: history, melachim-kings-book-of, yonah-jonah-book-of, literalism

I recently heard some scholars attempt to date Jonah as a later (and hence fictional) work.  Is it correct to assume that traditional Judaism considers Jonah to be a historical and accurate account of the real prophet described in the book of 2 Kings 14:25?

Comment: Who cares? Traditional Judaism definitely considers it to be Meaningful, Serious, and Significant.

Comment: The 'Who cares?' question is a different question and is a little more subjective. Just to clarify, this question is about gathering information information (i.e. is it held by Jewish groups to be historical), rather than wanting to discuss the implications and relevance of such a question. (Although that would certainly be an interesting question as well)

Comment: Tractate _Sukkah_ (Folio 55A) of the Jerusalem Talmud speaks to Jonah as the actual historical figure as depicted in the Book of Jonah.

Comment: @Jacob when people ask you who cares, ask them if they believe the exodus happened or creation, or if they are simply Meaningful Serious and Significant.

Comment: @user6591 If they are smart they'd answer you "Who cares?" and not get all flustered as if they were too dim to have thought about the logical extensions of their claim.

Comment: @Double and then I know they are heretics so when they offer me food to eat, I would decline. And when they are are the tenth man in shul, we don't have a minyan. And all other practical rules concerning orthoprax heretics.

Comment: @user6591 How would you know they are heretics?

Comment: @Double their indifference to the fundamentals of the Jewish religion.

Comment: @user6591 What indifference? It seems they have the fundamentals very much well identified, established and defended. Are you really going to call someone who doesn't take Genesis 1 literally (but rather in some sort of bigbang/schroeder/etc. way) an orthoprax heretic?

Comment: @Double I think chazzal told me not to talk to you about these matters because you will be pakkar tfei. Have a good day.

Comment: @user6591 I don't think they told you that. But your thinking so explains why you haven't had a chance to work through the issues and understand what's going on here. Thus I can give you a pass on being ignorant on the fundamentals of the Jewish religion bc of Oneis (you thought it was assur to learn).

Comment: @Jacob, are you asking about a person who went to Ninvei and motivated the people to Teshuva, or are you asking about a person who got swallowed by a sea-creature, survived for three days, and was regurgitated alive? It is theoretically possible to believe the former while believing the latter was part of a dream in the story, for example.

Comment: @doubleAA Schroeder doesn't deviate from the literal reading.

Comment: @HaLeiVi For some sense of 'deviate' and some sense of 'literal'. I'm sure you can find others who have given 'solutions' to that issue that take various liberties with determining the 'literal' meaning. Is everyone who says "Yom Echad" means a time period longer than 24 hours an 'orthoprax heretic'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mikra (the TaNaCh), as opposed to Aggadaic Medrashim and Talmudic passages, are not allegories. Even when the verse is hinting a lesson, we learn that אין מקרא יוצא מידי פשוטו, the verse does not abandon its simple meaning.

There are a few exceptions, though. Firstly, there is such a thing as exaggerations when that is a manner of speaking. A famous example of this is [the cities that reach the sky](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94%3A%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%90_%D7%9B%D7%97). This is an obvious figure of speech being employed. It 's not like something we'd read at face value, only to find out it never happened.

Another possible exception is the book of Iyov. There is [one opinion in the Gemara](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%91%D7%90_%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%98%D7%95_%D7%90) that Iyov never existed. However, this opinion was rejected because his name and location are given, which makes it read not like an allegory. So here too, we see that we won't interpret an innocent verse as a lesson without a literal truth.

In fact, the reason we interpret Talmudic passages as allegories is because they are also a figure of speech. It is not TaNach so it is less careful and it employs figurative speech, exaggerations and allegorical stories. These become obvious once you tune in.

The prophet Yona is counted as [one of the 48 prophets](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/The_List_of_Prophets.html).